# Showing Timer in android

Tags: android, timertask

My objective is to display a simple timer clock on my screen where it starts from 20 and goes on decreasing and when it becomes 0 I want to start an action.
How to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of timer clock? Do you want it to simply show the number of seconds before the action starts? Do you want it to be a GUI component?

Comment: I simply want to show the number of seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you want to display it but you can do this also just by taking a TextView and keep changing its Text every second.

```
static int i = 20;
 new CountdownTimer(20000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         i = i-1;
         mTextField.setText(String.valuOf(i));
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         //do your stuff here
     }
  }.start();
```