# Android Java countdown and then do somethign

Tags: java, android

How can i countdown to like 5 then something will happen?

Ex: Activity Starts it counts down to 5 then a toast comes up

Comment: this may give you an idea..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592863/showing-timer-in-android/7592908#7592908

Answer (score 3):

This you can perform by using [CountdownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) in-build abstract class

```
 new CountdownTimer(5000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
        // Now countdown is finished, perform whatever you want
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use Timer class

See this link for reference

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html